# simple_form inline on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am using a simple_form and bootstrap in rails 4. I want the start date and start time to be on the same line and end date and end time on the same line. I have tried the solutions from similar problems but none of them are working. I am a newbie in rails. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
        <%= b.input :start_date, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
        <%= b.input_field :start_date, class: "form-control date start" %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        <% end %>

        <%= b.input :start_time, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
        <%= b.input_field :start_time, as: :string, class: "form-control time start" %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
        <% end %>


        <%= b.input :end_date, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
        <%= b.input_field :end_date, class: "form-control date end" %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        <% end %>

        <%= b.input :end_time, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
        <%= b.input_field :end_time, as: :string, class: "form-control time end" %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
        <% end %>

        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getbootstrap.com/css/#grid this is what you should read. After wrapping your code with a `<div class="container"></div>` and inside that a `<div class="row"></div>` you can use the bootstrap columns to make your way and align everything perfectly.